# Using keras in R to perform neural network, my model has very low accuracy but the prediction is good and I don't know why

Tags: neural-network, keras, r

I used the classic dataset - mnist dataset that has 784 columns of pixels and 1 column of the label (from 0 to 9), and I was going to transform the images into their corresponding seven segment display representation. The following is my code.

```
# Convert the labels(digits) in train_set and test_set to seven-segment display
train_set$a <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9),1,0)
train_set$b <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9),1,0)
train_set$c <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),1,0)
train_set$d <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(0,2,3,5,6,8),1,0)
train_set$e <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(0,2,6,8),1,0)
train_set$f <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(0,4,5,6,8,9),1,0)
train_set$g <- ifelse(train_set$V1 %in% c(2,3,4,5,6,8,9),1,0)

test_set$a <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9),1,0)
test_set$b <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9),1,0)
test_set$c <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),1,0)
test_set$d <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(0,2,3,5,6,8),1,0)
test_set$e <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(0,2,6,8),1,0)
test_set$f <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(0,4,5,6,8,9),1,0)
test_set$g <- ifelse(test_set$V1 %in% c(2,3,4,5,6,8,9),1,0)

# Split the given train data to train_x and train_y
# Reshaping the training pixels and labels data to arrays
train_x <- as.matrix(train_set[, 2:785])
train_x <- array_reshape(train_x, c(nrow(train_x), 784))
train_y <- as.matrix(train_set[, 786:792])
train_y <- array_reshape(train_y, c(nrow(train_y), 7))

# Split the given test data to test_x and test_y
# Reshaping the testing pixels and labels data to arrays
test_x <- as.matrix(test_set[, 2:785])
test_x <- array_reshape(test_x, c(nrow(test_x), 784))
test_y <- as.matrix(test_set[, 786:792])
test_y <- array_reshape(test_y, c(nrow(test_y), 7))

# Normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
train_x <- train_x / 255
test_x <- test_x / 255

# Build the Model
image_size <- 784 # 28*28
num_classes <- 7 #7 segment display of the digits
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>%
  #Hidden Layers
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(image_size)) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  # Output Layer
  layer_dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'sigmoid')

# Summary of the model
summary(model)

# Compile the neural network
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = 'adam',
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

# Modeling on Training Dataset
model %>% fit(
  train_x, train_y,
  epochs = 5, batch_size = 128,
  validation_data = list(test_x, test_y)
)
# Prediction
pred <- predict_proba(model, test_x)
pred <- round(as.data.frame(pred))

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==1
                           & pred$V5==1 & pred$V6==1 & pred$V7==0,0,NA)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==0 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==0
                           & pred$V5==0 & pred$V6==0 & pred$V7==0,1,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==0 & pred$V4==1
                           & pred$V5==1 & pred$V6==0 & pred$V7==1,2,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==1
                           & pred$V5==0 & pred$V6==0 & pred$V7==1,3,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==0 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==0
                           & pred$V5==0 & pred$V6==1 & pred$V7==1,4,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==0 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==1
                           & pred$V5==0 & pred$V6==1 & pred$V7==1,5,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==0 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==1
                           & pred$V5==1 & pred$V6==1 & pred$V7==1,6,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==0
                           & pred$V5==0 & pred$V6==0 & pred$V7==0,7,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==1
                           & pred$V5==1 & pred$V6==1 & pred$V7==1,8,test_set$predict)

test_set$predict <- ifelse(pred$V1==1 & pred$V2==1 & pred$V3==1 & pred$V4==0
                           & pred$V5==0 & pred$V6==1 & pred$V7==1,9,test_set$predict)

confusionMatrix(factor(test_set$predict), factor(test_set$V1))
```

It turned out that my model always had only around 20% or 30% accuracy. However, when I used the model to do the prediction and transformed the outputs back into labels, the accuracy was quite good like roughly 85% every time.
I don't know what part is wrong with my model. Can someone help me out? Really appreciated!
The accuracy of my model:
[image]
The accuracy of my prediction:
[image]
The dataset can be downloaded here:
https://www.kaggle.com/zalando-research/fashionmnist
Here is the seven-segment display chart:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/805iH.png)

Comment: What do you meant that your model had 20% accuracy but then 85% accuracy?

Comment: I mean when I run the fit the model, for every epoch, the accuracy of my model is very low. But when I use the model to predict the testing data, I will have a prediction matrix of 7 columns and 3000 rows representing the seven-segment displays for my testing data. The I transform those segments back to the labels (from 0 to 9) using the seven_segment display chart and compare this predicted label with the original label in the testing group, I have around 85% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing two different accuracy concepts, hence the difference in values:

1. Your network is currently set-up to predict a value between 0 and 1 for each label (activation = 'sigmoid'). In this case you might get an output like [0.9 0.4 0.3 ... 0.2] etc. If you use this set-up and the measure 'accuracy' Keras will infer that you want to calculate binary accuracy. This is not the same as categorical accuracy
2. When you run the prediction part you are using categorical accuracy.

To fix your problem change:

1. set the final layer activation function to 'softmax'
2. use 'categorical cross entropy' loss function

In this case, Keras should recognize that you want to measure categorical accuracy.

Comment: I am not trying to predict the label here. I am trying to predict the seven-segment display here. I already transformed the label into a seven-segment display. For example, the first image is a 9, then it will be illuminated in a, b, c, f, g columns according to the chart I provided at the end, so in these columns, the values are assigned to 1, but for d and e columns, the values are assigned to 0. My y in the model is a 7 column and 3000 row matrix, and I need to used the model to predict if the image will be illuminated in certain columns or not, so the value of my output layer nodes is 7.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Can you try running  the 'evaluate` function of the model using the test data, this should return a test accuracy.  I still think their is a difference between how Keras calculate the accuracy and accuracy reported in the confusion matrix

Comment: I just did and the test accuracy is like 30%. And I actually run this model in python, all the parameters are the same, the model accuracy is above 90%. The dataset and the model are exactly the same I used in R, but the model accuracy in R is always low.